# Removing duplicates from CSV

Tags: powerapps

I have a CSV data from an external data. I need to remove the duplicates, but can't execute the following code on it.

```
    Distinct(
            Split(
                CSV,
                ","
            ),
        ThisRecord
    )
```

nor

```
    Distinct(
        ForAll(
            Split(
                CSV,
                ","
            ),
            Result
        ),
        ThisRecord
    )
```

I intend to use this to feed a dropdown, however it does not display any items when attached to the dropdown. I also tried to create a table from these outputs, however it says this does not work because it is a nonrecord value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that you have in your CSV, and what do you mean by removing duplicates? For example, if you have columns A, B, and C, would a duplicate be columns where all values are the same (i.e., A, B and C), only one of them (and in this case, which of the different values of the other columns do you want)?

Comment: The data is very simple, is it only one column data, that will be used to populate a dropdown. An example of the data is as follows: CC, EC, EX, AB

Comment: Are 'CC', 'EC', 'EX', 'AB' each on its own row, or do you have multiple rows with those values separated by commas?

Comment: No multiple rows, they come in a single text field, literally like this "CC,EC,EX,AB,CC" I need to split them, and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If the values that you want to split and take the distinct ones are in a single text field, then you can use an expression like the following:

```
Distinct(
    Split(CSV, ","),
    Result
)
```

If the values are in multiple rows, and you want to remove from all of the rows, then it depends on what you really want to do. Take this example:

| SingleRow |
| --- |
| CC,EC,EX,AB,CC |
| AB,CC,FE,AB,FE |
| TT,CD,FE,GG,TT |

If you want to remove the duplicates *on each individual row*, while having the result as a table (that can be used as the Default property of a dropdown, for example), then you can use something like the following expression:

```
ForAll(
  CSV,
  {
    UniqueValues:
      Distinct(
        Split(ThisRecord.SingleRow, ","),
        Result
      )
  })
```

That expression can be used in a gallery, and inside the gallery you can have a dropdown control with its Default property set to ThisItem.Value.

If you want the distinct values *across all rows*, then you can use something like the expression below:

```
Distinct(
  Split(
    Concat(CSV, SingleRow, ","),
    ","),
  Result)
```

For the table above you'll get a result with 8 rows, each with one of the unique values (CC,EC,EX,AB,FE,TT,CD,GG)